# Who is the man in the credit scene in The Amazing Spider-Man?

Tags: credits, the-amazing-spider-man

In [The Amazing Spider-Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/), in the post credit scene **Dr. Curt Connors** is in a jail cell and he was talking with someone, but his face was never shown in the movie due to shadows. Here is the [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-NDoaMxgP8) of that scene.  Also, this is a still image from the scene:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea *who the man is in the credit scene in The Amazing Spider-Man?*

Comment: The audio leads me to believe it is Norman Osbourne as it sounds like Willam Dafoe from the original series.

Comment: Rumors abound that Spidey will be facing the Sinister Six at some point in the new franchise - so this could well be one of them. The Vulture has also been rumored. Personally, I think it's Pete's dad.

Comment: [According to Rhys Ifans](http://www.aintitcool.com/node/56771) it's __not__ Norman Osborne, `but it is someone who is in the employ of Norman Osborn without question.`

Comment: maybe the chamaleon? lets remember the bots he made up of peters parents

Comment: This is already on the SciFi.SE site, if that means anything to its existence here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/19936/

Comment: I thought Norman Osborne, but did he survive after? Didn't he also need the formula Connors created? Great point made by Ben that it is actually Connors talking to himself!

Comment: I thought it said Richard and Mary Parker were killed in the plane crash.

Comment: @chris The fate of Peter's parents is [unclear](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3174/209).

Answer (score 6):

Having watched it again, and continuing with the Sinister Six theory I mentioned earlier, I now believe this might be the introduction of Electro.
If you'll recall, the figure appears and disappears during lightning strikes, which would be the perfect cover (and set up) for Electro.
Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think Electro features pretty prominently in the game of the movie, which might not mean much, but could be another clue.

Comment: Ahem... anyone see the news lately? :)

Comment: Anyone can predict the future nowadays

Answer (score 6):

Well, according to [this page](http://amazingspiderman.wikia.com/wiki/Gustav_Fiers) on The Amazing Spider Man Wikia, *and* Entertainment Weekly, this is **Gustav Fiers, AKA The Gentleman**, a sinister figure with ties to Oscorp and the [Sinister Six](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinister_Six#Novels). From EW (about a scene in the 2nd movie):

> The final moments also feature a scene with Harry, now in his own cell in Ravencroft, taking a call from **The Gentleman otherwise known as Mr. Fiers (whom we all remember from his appearance at the end of the first film.)** Harry is looking better — we can assume that the Goblin suit equalized his condition enough so that he could be functional — and he talks about putting together a team to beat Spider-Man. Important phrasing in this short scene: “I want to keep it small.” Without question, **this is our introduction to the Sinister Six, as we then see The Gentleman start to peruse the goods in the special lab section of Oscorp** (key among them: Doc Ock’s arms, Vulture’s wings, and the Rhino suit.)

[Here's the link](http://popwatch.ew.com/2014/05/02/amazing-spider-man-2-ending-dissecting-final-moments-spoilers/). [MTV](http://www.mtv.com/news/1819363/amazing-spider-man-2-easter-eggs/) (scroll to the bottom) and [The Toronto Sun](http://www.torontosun.com/2014/05/02/sinister-six-villains-revealed-in-the-amazing-spider-man-2) (4th paragraph from the end) also seem to treat it as fact.

Comment: ...And I only realized just now that this question is 2 years old. Sorry if this is a known fact by now.

Comment: Considering the new movie is out and could probably reveal this person's identity, your answer is still very much relevant and appreciated :D

Comment: @Walt If it wasn't adressed yet in any of the other answers, you can safely consider it an unknown fact. There is absolutely no problem to answer decades old stuff if new information arises.

Answer (score 2):

I believe he's actually talking to himself.  Like he did earlier when he found out that Spiderman was Peter Parker.  He had a conversation in his head about what to do.
Now that he is in his cell, I feel the filmmaker just showed it how Connors saw it in his head.
Remember, he's in a jail cell.  If I remember right, when they opened the door to the cell it was empty.  How would Osborne be able to have a secret door into his cell?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's Norman Osborne because it wouldn't make sense. Curt is in jail, how could Norman get in there. I think it's between Dr. Connors' conscience, or it could be Peter's dad, because they never showed what happened to him.  Plus, remember Peter went on a computer and looked up info about his dad, and they said Peters mom and dad died in a plane crash